# Scheme function to take a list and an atom as parameters and returns index of the first location where atom occurs

Tags: list, function, scheme

I'm very new to Scheme and am working on a problem defined as follows:

Write a scheme function find-loc which takes two parameters, a list lst and an atom atm, and returns the index of the first location where atm occurs in the list. 
The location index is 1-relative. If atm does not occur in the list, the function returns n + 1, where n is the length of the list.

what I've got so far is:

```
(define (find-loc list atm)
  (if (not(list? list))
     0 
    (cond
      ((null? list)
        1)
      ((eq? (car list)atm)
        1))
       (else (+ (find-loc (cdr list atm) 1) )))
```

I feel that I'm close but am a bit stuck.  My main questions are as follows:

1. how do I define what the atom is?
2. why am I getting the following error?   "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An atom is defined by this predicate:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (null? x))
       (not (pair? x))))
```

The error you're receiving is because the syntax of the `if` expression is incorrect - it must have two parts after the condition (consequent and alternative), and you wrote three. A few comments:

- It's better to use a `cond` when testing for multiple conditions
- Don't name a variable as `list`, it clashes with a built-in procedure of the same name
- Better use `equal?` for testing equality, it's more general
- We should use our new and shiny `atom?` predicate, as per the requirements - even though the `null?` check is redundant at this point

This is what I mean:

```
(define (find-loc lst atm)
  (cond ((not (list? lst)) 0)
        ((null? lst) 1)
        ((and (atom? (car lst)) (equal? (car lst) atm)) 1)
        (else (+ 1 (find-loc (cdr lst) atm)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am getting the following error: pair?: this function is not defined

Comment: @GScott it's because of the language you're using. Try switching to a different language (in Racket, select the option "determine language from source" and include this line at the start of the file: `#lang racket`). Otherwise, there isn't much we can do - `pair?` is a primitive procedure, it can't be implemented in terms of others. As a last resort, you can remove the `atom?` check and forget about it, because anyway we're already checking for `list?` and `null?` in the previous lines.

Comment: thank you, that seems to have worked. Thanks for taking the time to help a struggling student

Comment: This probably don't work as function in other languages that usually return -1 if item was not found, your code will return 4 for 3 items if not found. So it's not much of use for others then OP that didn't need that behavior.